# How to show the ID in another form field?

Tags: infopath, list-form

I am building a InfoPath form in SharePoint and I would like to use the ID Counter in another field so I can rename it to something else. I would also like the count in the new field to be ID+5000, for example the first form submitted would have the ID 1, but new field would show 5001

Hope this makes sense! Any help would be great on how I can do this, I have tried everything..

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the `ID` until the form is saved. Only after submitting the list item, the `ID` should be generated. You should able to get the previous items `ID` and add `5001` to that ID and then assign the value to another field.

Steps to get the previous item ID:

- In infopath designer, click `Data Connections` in Data tab
- Add new connection and choose recieve data
- Click next and choose SharePoint library or list
- Give the URL and select the current list you are working
- By default the Id field is selected, Click next
- Finish the setting and go to the field that you want to set new value
- In the fields properties, click default value ***fx*** button
- Insert function -> max() -> double click to insert field
- In that click the *Show Advanced view*
- In drop-down choose your data connection name and in data-fields you will get the id, Select the ID and Click OK.
- Add 5001 to that value

Thats it. Make this as Answer.

Comment: What formula would you use for this? Thanks

Comment: Answer edited please check this and make this as answer. Thank you

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid, where do I add 5000 to it?

Comment: Build your formula like this `max(ID) + 5001`

Comment: Whenever I add the formula to +5001 I get errors on sharepoint.

Comment: @user3560464 What does your formula look like?

Comment: It is: max(ID)+5000

Comment: @user3560464 Is the ID field that you put in your formula the ID from your data connection?

Comment: Yes they both from the same form. My new field is called Small Change ID

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Did you get the ID from the new data connection or Main Connection?? and What is the error you got?

Comment: Please verify, in the **10th step** you are choosing the data connection from drop down should be the new one not the `Main Connection`

Comment: It is working now, but you can only see the number by clicking 'View Item' on SharePoint, it does not show it in the List View, it is blank. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Sorry it actually isnt working - It is working for forms already submitted, but if I submit a new form is comes up with the error: The form cannot be submitted.
One or more fields have invalid values and cannot be submitted to the list.
Invalid number value.
A number field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again.
Correlation ID:4fe75eee-90af-48a6-bf44-8f11099ad214

Comment: I can't understand what your saying? Please explain me clearly?